# Node.js Socket.io chat server SSL

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, socket.io

i am trying to get my chat app in node.js/socket.io to work on SSL (https), i am now at the moment i dont get errors when i startup the server but i cant connect anymore.

I googled and tried so much examples but i cant get it to work.

This was my old code (this works in http)

```
    var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

This is my changed code:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('cert.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt')
};

var express = require('express')
  , app = express();

var server = https.createServer(options);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I created the https server on node. Try it once it is working fine for me .

```
var port = "80";
var express = require('express')
, app = express()
, http = require('http')
, server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);

var fs = require('fs');
var net = require('net');
var tls = require('tls');
var sslOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('public/server.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('public/server.crt')
};
tls.createServer(sslOptions, function (cleartextStream) {
    var cleartextRequest = net.connect({
        port: port, //your port
        host: serverStr // your server address
    }, function () {
        cleartextStream.pipe(cleartextRequest);
        cleartextRequest.pipe(cleartextStream);
    });
}).listen(443);
```

Comment: thanks for helping, I am getting this error: `events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1043:14)
    at listen (net.js:1065:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1139:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/app.js:6:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)`

Comment: Change the port, something else is running on that port number.

Comment: Same error when i change the port, i am running a webserver on port 80 is that the problem?

Comment: can be , it is default port for http and 443 is default port of https. Open command prompt and use netstat -b , it'll show you all active port and processes.

Comment: something was running on the port, ive tried a different one it works thanks!